# Rearrange seasonalized von Bertalanffy growth equation to solve for age

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm hoping someone can help me rearrange the following equation to solve for $t$:

$L_t = L_{inf} * (1-e^{-K*(t-t_0)
  + (CK/2\pi*sin(2\pi*(t-t_s)))
  - (CK/2\pi*sin(2\pi*(t_0-t_s)))
})$

The "seasonally oscillating von Bertalanffy growth function" (soVBGF) is commonly used to model fish length at age $t$, $L_t$, based on a maximum possible length, $L_{inf}$, and growth constant, $K$, a theoretical age when length equals zero ($L_t=0$), $t_0$, a "summer point" when growth is at a maximum, $t_s$, and the strength of the oscillation, $C$ ranging from zero to one ($0<=C<=1)$.

An example of the resulting function looks like this:

[image]

I have been successful in rearranging a simpler, non-oscillating version of the VBGF:

$L_t = L_{inf} * (1-e^{-K*(t-t_0)})$,

which results in:

$t=(1/-K) * log(1-(L_t/L_{inf}))+t_0$

Thanks for your help.

#### P.S. If someone can help suggesting tags for this question, I would be most appreciative.